# Map function into global variable in swift error " Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that '[_]' conform to 'LosslessStringConvertible'"

Tags: swift, dictionary, global-variables, swift4

I have this JSON data that I just parse with JSONDecoder. I have made a struct to decode this JSON data and I want this value from that JSON to be a global variable so I can pass it to other controller. I already make this global variable and I just want to put my JSON variable into this global variable.

Since it's an `Int` and my global variable is a `string`, so I'm trying to convert it first with : `var a = string(jsonvalue)`, but I get this error:

> Initializer `'init(_:)'` requires that `'[_]'` conform to 'LosslessStringConvertible'

All of this I search it from web, I'm still a junior developer so I need your help please to finish my project.

this is my global variable :

```
            struct GlobalVariable {

                static var ProjectId = String() //project id
                static var UserId = String() // User Id
                var GroupId = String() // group Id
                static var Status = String() //Status for login 

                init(dictionary : [String : Any]) {
                    id = dictionary ["id"] as! Int
                    name = dictionary ["name"] as! String
                    email = dictionary ["email"] as! String
                    status = dictionary ["status"] as! String
                }

                enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
                   case id = "id"
                   case name = "name"
                   case email = "email"
                   case status = "status"
                }
            }
        }

        var Loginnn = [login]()

        struct login : Codable {
            let id : Int
            let name : String
            let email : String
            let status : String
        }

        let parsing = try JSONDecoder().decode([login].self,    from: data)
        print(parsing)
        self.Loginnn = parsing

        //This is for login verification
        let stats = self.Loginnn.map { $0.status}

        //this is the Id value I try to make into global Variable
        let ids = self.Loginnn.map { $0.id} // I use this map    function to extract that value and put it into the variable 

        GlobalVariable.UserId = String(ids)// I use string to   convert from int to string. --> this is where the error begin 


        if stats.contains("1"){ // Login Success
            print("Login Success")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.appDelegate.loginSeque()
            }
        }else if stats.isEmpty {//fail login 
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Got It", style: .default, handler: nil)
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Wrong Email / Password", message: "Please Try Again ", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(action)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
}.resume()
```

from that line of code : `let ids = self.Loginnn.map { $0.id}`, I am able to get that id value from `JSONDecoder`, but when I try to put it into the global variable it shows error like this:

> Initializer `'init(_:)'` requires that `'[_]'` conform to 'LosslessStringConvertible'

I need help, because I'm still a junior developer, so I don't know if this code is correct or not.

Comment: Your code is syntactically incorrect and incomplete. Can you replace it with [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)?

Comment: You are trying to initialize a String object with an array, you need to use a loop or only get the first element of the array

Comment: @JoakimDanielson a loop like what to be exactly? what should i loop? im sorry if i dont understand since im new in this swift developer i just learn it about 3 months now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only get one row back in your json message, or only the first one is interesting you can do

```
if let id = ids.first {
    let GlobalVariable.UserId = String(id)
}
```